# Theano, print intermediate shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano

I have just switched from using tensorflow to theano due to lack of tensorflow support on the system I am working on.  The thing I find the most annoying about theano is the lack of shape information with the tensors.  Printing the intermediate shapes is my main source of debugging when using tensorflow.  In theano I know I can print the shapes by creating fake input and evaluating the shape.  This works for most cases except when I want to look at an intermediate result in a scan.  I can view the contents of a tensor using `x = theano.printing.Print()(x)` however if I were to use `x = theano.printing.Print()(x.shape)` now x is assigned to its shape which breaks everything.  Is there a way to print intermediate shape?  I think This problem could be resolved if there were a feature like tensorflow's control_dependencies() function in theano.

Comment: I guess an easier trick would be to create a [theano function](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/function.html) to return the shape/value etc. of variables within intermediate steps. Then you can use the normal python's `print(..)` to view the shape etc.

Comment: I have done that but I don't see how that works inside of a scan.